# Can't publish to NPM

Tags: javascript, github, npm, npm-publish, npm-package

I've been trying to publish this but I keep getting this error:

I first logged in with: npm login

Once logged in I just run: npm publish

This is my repo: https://github.com/hypetf/pcm-converter

```
npm publish
npm notice
npm notice package: pcm-converter@1.0.0
npm notice === Tarball Contents ===
npm notice 1.1kB LICENSE
npm notice 1.7kB README.md
npm notice 697B  convert.test.js
npm notice 1.5kB index.js
npm notice 1.1kB package.json
npm notice 344B  test/test.js
npm notice === Tarball Details ===
npm notice name:          pcm-converter
npm notice version:       1.0.0
npm notice filename:      pcm-converter-1.0.0.tgz
npm notice package size:  2.8 kB
npm notice unpacked size: 6.5 kB
npm notice shasum:        1da2fb842445917d5bcaa66a0e2f344d61c654a6
npm notice integrity:     sha512-LmpfE40HyJREu[...]kqjM2mXxCvYMA==
npm notice total files:   6
npm notice
npm notice Publishing to https://npm.pkg.github.com
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://npm.pkg.github.com/pcm-converter
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'pcm-converter@1.0.0' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

I tried logging in with both:
npm login --auth-type=legacy --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com

and: npm login

It logs in successfully both times, and even done `npm adduser`

When running `npm whoami` it does display my username.

But why do I still get the error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try logging with *scope*
`npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com --scope=@hypetf`

Comment: I tried, it does login, but when I try `npm publish` I get the same error.

Comment: In `package.json`, change name to `"name": "@hypetf/pcm-converter"` and then try